# My fs.writeFile won't log anything into my JSON file?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am creating a Discord.js Bot currently, and I am trying to create a prefix and have it log into the JSON file, however, using fs.writeFile, it will not log anything into the file, is there something I am doing wrong?

```
try {

      //Checks User Permissions
      if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_SERVER")) return;
      if(!args[0]) return;

      //Calls the prefixes.json file
      let prefixes = require('../prefixes.json');

      //Fetches the prefix they want to change
      prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
        prefixes: args[0]
      };

      //Logs the Prefix for the Guild
      fs.writeFile("../prefixes.json", JSON.stringify(prefixes), (err) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
      })

      //Main Embed Code
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor('Prefix Changed!')
            .setDescription(`The new prefix for ${message.guild.name} is set to \`${args[0]}\`!`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor(colours.main)

            message.channel.send(embed)
 } catch(e) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(colours.red)
            .setDescription(`Error:\`\`\`${e.message}\`\`\``)
           message.channel.send(embed)
    }};
```

Comment: Does it show you some logs, errors?

Comment: Personally, i will use database.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov No errors, nothing wrong has been shown, it just doesn't log anything into the main file.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code at first glance. It requires more information to help debug this one.

Comment: I have edited the code to show the exact current code I have for that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `fs.writeFileSync()`, it's just easier unless the async version is absolutely needed. If you are trying to perform an operation on that file after `fs.writeFile()` is called, it's done asynchronously, so you'd have to make sure the `writeFile()` is done before resuming any other operations relevant to that file.